# Remove excess height size on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, office-365-developer

[image: Please refer image]

Hi Developers, We had SharePoint list and we customised the list as per our requirement. But we are facing some excess space height issue on list. Please refer attached image. We want to remove the height "style="display: block; height: 318.4px". Can anyone please suggest, how to remove the excess height. Please let us know, if you need any additional information.

SharePoint online environment we are using.

Comment: Is this a list form? How you have customized it? Also, can you please share the code you used? Is this a default inline CSS or you have applied it through your custom code? also try using `div.ui-accordion-content { height: auto !important }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the CSS style below into script editor web part in list form page to achieve it.

```
<style>
#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0{
    height:auto !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]